# NodeJS set environment variable for exec

Tags: node.js

I want to set an environment variable when running a program via `child_process.exec`. Is this possible?

I tried setting the `env` like this:

```
exec('FOO', {'FOO': 'ah'}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {console.log(stdout, stderr, error);});
```

but the resulting message said FOO did not exist.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You have to pass an options object that includes the key **env** whose value is itself an object of key value pairs.

```
exec('echo $FOO', {env: {'FOO': 'ah'}}, function (error, stdout, stderr) 
{
    console.log(stdout, stderr, error);
});
```

Comment: Anyone using this should take note that specifying environment variables this way replaces the _entire_ set of environment variables, *including* any `PATH` that might otherwise exist. So, if you try to set an env variable and you suddenly get errors about the command you're trying to exec not being found, this is why. This isn't clear at all from the documentation and left me scratching my head for a bit. If you want to add env variables and stay platform-agnostic, you could make a copy of `process.env`, apply your changes to that,  and pass it to `child_process.exec`.

Comment: You can also update `process.env` direclty. Ex: `process.env["PATH"] += path.delimiter + process.cwd() + path.sep + "node_modules" + path.sep + ".bin"`

Comment: complementing @DanielSmedegaardBuus answer, you can use the spread operator for it.
`env: { ...process.env,  'FOO': 'ah'}`

Answer (score 40):

Based on @DanielSmedegaardBuus answer, you have to **add** your env var to the existing ones, if you want to preserve them:

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec(
  "echo $FOO", 
  { env: { ...process.env, FOO: "ah" } }, 
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout, stderr, error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I should've written :D My name is DanielSmedegaardBuus, and I endorse this message :D