# How does the nodejs exec() function loads a bash environment?

Tags: node.js, bash, exec

I recently stumbled upon an error where a process launched by the `exec()` function failed because it could not find a environment variable.

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824789/nodejs-set-environment-variable-for-exec) on SO but I now have a question.

Which bash environment does the `exec()` function from `child_process` loads ? (not sure if the question is well written so I'll explain a bit more).

```
// app.js
const {exec} = require('child_process');
const http = require('http');

// Create an instance of the http server to handle HTTP requests
let app = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // Set a response type of plain text for the response
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    exec('echo $PATH > foo.txt');   // <<<<<<<<

    // Send back a response and end the connection
    res.end('Hello World!\n');
});

// Start the server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Node server running on port 3000');
```

If I run the code above I get the `foo.txt` file with the content of `$PATH` inside, meaning the shell environment spawned by `exec()` can find the environment variables.

However if I try to change `$PATH` to `$MY_OWN_VARIABLE` it cannot find it even though I added in the `.bashrc` the line `export MY_OWN_VARIABLE="foo bar baz"`.

(For testing purposes I am working in a VM as root so I changed the root bashrc).

It seems like the `exec()` is not using the bashrc while spawning a shell but it stills find some variables such as `$PATH` but not the ones I defined and I don't know why.

This is only pure curiosity, the solution linked above solved my issue but it's still bothering me.

Note: I am not familiar with node and probably not with how a bash shell is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to restart your root session and check if `$MY_OWN_VARIABLE` is set with `echo $MY_OWN_VARIABLE`. Probably just a session restart is needed.